# data extraction of all social apps in one app

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, backend, data-extraction

We want to develop a web app which should include social apps like Facebook, Instagram etc . How can we integrate them all together in one app so we could perform data extraction on the user's data?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the social media platforms have exposed their APIs. so you can integrate them all in your app.

Comment: you can check this [link](https://blog.api.rakuten.net/top-10-best-social-media-apis/) for Top 10 Social Media APIs